# Clang: generated .o file incompatible with elf64-x86-64

Tags: c, clang, cross-compiling, sparc, ubsan

I am trying to cross compile with clang and run Undefined Behavior Sanitizer for .c file

**Command I am running**

```
clang -target sparc -integrated-as -fuse-ld=lld -fsanitize=undefined test1.c
```

clang is the cross compiler

sparc is the target architecture.

-integrated-as to use the llvm assembler

-fuse-ld=lld to use lld linker

-fsanitize=undefined to run UBSan

**Error**

ld.lld: error: /tmp/test1-43c7c0.o is incompatible with elf64-x86-64

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

clang-11: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**My system**

Ubuntu 18.04

x86_64

command executed on ubuntu terminal

without -target sparc on a file.c which does not contain sparc assembly the clang works fine